Supabase SQL: Allow company owner to access all employee data while restricting employees to their own data
I'm developing a Next.js application with Supabase as the backend. I need to implement Row Level Security (RLS) policies that allow a company owner to view and manage data for all employees in their company, while restricting regular employees to only their own data. My setup includes separate authentication and employee tables.
Database structure:

auth.users table (managed by Supabase):

id (PK, uuid)
email


company table:

company_id (PK)
company_name


employee table:

id (PK)
user_id (FK to auth.users.id)
company_id (FK to company table)
employee_name
employee_permission (e.g., 'owner', 'employee')


work_time table:

id (PK)
employee_id (FK to employee.id)
user_id (FK to auth.users.id)
start_time
end_time



I've tried implementing the following policy for the work_time table, but it's not working as expected:
CREATE POLICY "Owners can view all work time in their company" ON work_time
FOR SELECT USING (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM employee AS e
    WHERE e.user_id = auth.uid() 
    AND e.employee_permission = 'owner'
    AND e.company_id = (SELECT company_id FROM employee WHERE id = work_time.employee_id)
  )
);

Any guidance on structuring these policies correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

